# Restaurar base de datos Mysql en Centos desde un archivo .sql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, linux

Hola verán tengo un archivo .sql de una base de datos de un proyecto pero esta en windows y lo necesito tener en linux asi que a traves de FTP pase el archivo a una maquina virtual con centos. Entonces ya con ese archivo, ¿puedo generar la base de datos? Ya tengo instalado el MYSQL
.
.
ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entra por ssh al servidor que corre Centos. Luego ejecuta el siguiente comando:

```
mysql -u usuario -p base_de_datos < data.sql
```

Donde `usuario` es el usuario de la base de datos, `base_de_datos` es el nombre de la base de datos y `data.sql` es el nombre del respaldo de la base de datos.
Este comando realizará la importación y restauración de la base de datos con el archivo `.sql` facilitado.

Comment: dejame ver si entendi. ingreso por SSH a centos y alli ejecuto ese comando?

Comment: Edité la respuesta para para ver si queda más claro.

Comment: Gracias Marco :)

Comment: ya lo hice bro y me sale ERROR unknow database bodega. la sintaxis esta bien:  mysql -u root -p bodega < "/home/ftp/productos.sql"

Comment: Creaste anteriormente la base de datos?

Comment: Haz esto, "mysql -u root -p" y luego pon "CREATE DATABASE bodega"

Comment: A si es cierto, que p****** soy. No la habia creado, muchas gracias viejo. Te amo, crack